# R - Getting NaN value and error message for chi-squared test (rows with zeros)

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

I have some trouble to calculate chi squared statistic with R.

My data and code are:

```
>   library(MASS)

> dput(wstocks_lo)
structure(c(0.528307031905727, 0.0239930086670024, 0.430621410717852, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0170785487094175, 0, 0, 0, 0.205292252213616, 0, 
0.794707747786385, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.205292252213616, 0, 0.794707747786385, 
0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(9L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("AUS", "BEL", 
"CAN", "FRA", "GER", "JPN", "NED", "SWE", "USA"), c("wstocksp1_lo", 
"wstocksp2_lo", "wstocksp3_lo")))

> chisq.test(wstocks_lo)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  wstocks_lo
X-squared = NaN, df = 16, p-value = NA

Warning message:
In chisq.test(wstocks_lo) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this? Is it a good idea to just delete the rows that consists only of zeros or will that give a disorted picture of the results? Should I maybe consider another test? What is the best solution?

Because if I do that I get the following:

```
> dput(test)
structure(c(0.528307031905727, 0.0239930086670024, 0.430621410717852, 
0, 0.0170785487094175, 0, 0, 0.205292252213616, 0.794707747786385, 
0, 0, 0, 0.205292252213616, 0.794707747786385, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(c("AUS", "BEL", "CAN", "GER", "SWE"), c("wstocksp1_lo", 
"wstocksp2_lo", "wstocksp3_lo")))
> chisq.test(test)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  test
X-squared = 2.0542, df = 8, p-value = 0.9793

Warning message:
In chisq.test(test) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Comment: Moderators:  It appears the intent of this question is not about the R function, but about how to analyze data of this type.

Answer (score 1):

An underlying problem is that your table is not a table of counts, but a table of percentages.  Chi-square tests of association and similar tests need counts.

Aside from this, it's not clear to me what you are trying to determine.

```
Input =("
wstocksp1_lo wstocksp2_lo wstocksp3_lo
AUS   0.52830703    0.0000000    0.0000000
BEL   0.02399301    0.0000000    0.0000000
CAN   0.43062141    0.2052923    0.2052923
FRA   0.00000000    0.0000000    0.0000000
GER   0.00000000    0.7947077    0.7947077
JPN   0.00000000    0.0000000    0.0000000
NED   0.00000000    0.0000000    0.0000000
SWE   0.01707855    0.0000000    0.0000000
USA   0.00000000    0.0000000    0.0000000
")

wstocks_lo = as.matrix(read.table(textConnection(Input),
                   header=TRUE,
                   row.names=1))

colSums(wstocks_lo)

   ### wstocksp1_lo wstocksp2_lo wstocksp3_lo 
   ###           1            1            1
```

Comment: I try to test the null hypothesis that wstocksp1_lo = wstocksp2_lo = wstocksp3_lo. However, I am not sure which test is appropriate for this. These are indeed the decimal version of percentages (e.g. 0.5283 = 52.83%)

Comment: You might be looking for something akin to the chi-square test of association (that you tried), but if so, the table needs to be composed of counts, not percentages.  (If this makes sense for your data.)  Even so, all those zeros may play havoc with the test, and you may need to use an exact variant, or one based on resampling.